# Run function when another function finishes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a page is done refreshing, jQuery event is launched:

```
$(#id).trigger('reloaded');
```

'reloaded' is a custom event;

How do i set up a listener , such that, when it is done 'reloading' , i run another function:

I was thinking about this:

```
$(#id).on('reloaded',function(ev) {
    alert("LAUNCH function");
});
```

But this doesnt work

Comment: That depends on what `'reloading'` consists of.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing.  Have you looked at the docs for `trigger()` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ and the docs for the `load()` event http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ ?

Comment: That looks to me like it ought to work. Are you sure the "reloaded" listener as added before the event is triggered?

Comment: Why dont you include the call to your second function at the end of the reloadFunction??

Comment: `'reloaded'` is not a javascript event, do you maybe mean `'load'`?

Comment: Please add more details explaining exactly what you need to have happen before you run the new code.  And does the code run at the wrong time?  or not run at all?

Comment: What does "jQuery is launched" mean?

Comment: @SuviVignarajah he's triggering a custom event.  Thats jQuery's pub-sub mechanism

Comment: Your missing a quote in your `alert("launch function")`;

Comment: @ben336 I stand corrected. Then I see nothing wrong with that code, aside from the syntax issues @Sebastien mentioned, as well as quotes around the selector `'#id'`

Comment: [DEMO: What you have is just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4vTy/) What behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ . Pass a function reference as the second parameter to `.trigger()`. Then in the `reloaded` handler, access this passed function and call it at the end of your asynchronous code

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quote in your `alert()`

it should look like this:

```
$('#id').on('reloaded',function(ev){
            alert("LAUNCH function");

            });
```

EDIT: quotes in the selector thanks to @Pinocchio

Comment: Quotes in the selector aswell that is not a valid variable nane